# Laravel - Attach method throwes exception

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I got the following tables

- actors

  1. id
  2. name
- stats

  1. id
  2. name
- actor_stat

  1. actor_id
  2. stat_id
  3. quantity

I want, given an actor, insert an element in actor_stat.

Code in the controller

```php
$actor = Actor::where('name', $actor->name)->first();
$actor->stats()->attach(10); //10 is the id of an existing stat
$actor->save();
```

Actor's model

```php
class Actor extends Model
{
    public function stats()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Stat', 'actor_stat')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
}
```

Stat's model

```php
class Stat extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'actor_stat')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
}
```

Problem is it throwes an exception, I can't read the log 'cause permession denied. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I had not nullable attributes in the pivot table, so I had to give them a value.